# Retrieving numbers from an alphanumeric text file using a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am outputting the results of a timed executable to a file that has run 10 times. I have all the times in a file, and I need to find the best, worst, and average user times from this file. I was thinking about using a combination of awk to print the first column, but I am unsure how to strip "user" from the line so I can sort it numerically.

Also, I would need to get rid of the even rows, since they have information about the inputs and outputs and things that don't matter to these calculations.
A sample of the time file is below:

```
1.12user 0.00system 0:01.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5408maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+398minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I would do this?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: you can get best,worst,avg in one-shot. updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this ok for you?

```
awk -F'user' 'NR%2{print $1}' file
```

with an example:

```
kent$  cat file
1.11user 0.00system 0:01.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5408maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+398minor)pagefaults 0swaps
1.10user 1.00system 0:01.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5408maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+398minor)pagefaults 0swaps
1.12user 2.00system 0:01.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5408maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+398minor)pagefaults 0swaps
1.13user 3.00system 0:01.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5408maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+398minor)pagefaults 0swaps

kent$  awk -F'user' 'NR%2{print $1}' file
1.11
1.10
1.12
1.13
```

Even this maybe?

```
 awk -F'user' 'NR%2{a[++i]=$1;s+=$1}END{asort(a);print "best: "a[1];print "worst: "a[length(a)];print "avg: "s/length(a)}' file
```

the above example will output:

```
best: 1.10
worst: 1.13
avg: 1.115
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! I will vote up as soon as I have the reputation to do so.

Comment: Is there a way to print best and worst with head and tail after I sort the list, out of curiosity? I thought I got it to work, but each one prints 01 about 10 times. Odd

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -s ' '  '[:alpha:]' < inputfile | awk '{print $1, $2, $3} ' > newfile
```

There other variations to do the same thing.

Comment: I tried that, and it returns: `tr: when translating, the only character classes that may appear in
string2 are `upper' and `lower'`
'

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the initial number #user.

```
cat txt | paste - - | cut -d' ' -f1  | tr -d "[:alpha:]" | sort -n
```

gives:

```
1.12
1.13
1.14
1.15
1.16
```

on my example of your txt with numbers changed to prove sorting.